# Insert data from buckets to tables of Cloud SQL for SQL Server instance using local python

Tags: python, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to insert data (txt files) from `buckets` to `Cloud SQL` for `SQL Server` instance using my local python.

I can connect to the buckets but I have trouble connecting to the SQL Server instance and make a insert data from the txt files

```
import os, sys
from google.cloud import storage

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'ServiceKey_GooglCloud.json' 
storage_client = storage.Client()

mybucket= storage_client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
```

Do you know a way in python to insert data in the tables of the SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Cloud SQL Python connector` :

[Github Cloud SQL Python connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector)

[PyPi Cloud SQL Python connector](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector)

According the documentation, the Cloud SQL Python Connector is a package to be used alongside a database driver. Currently supported drivers are:

```
pymysql (MySQL)
pg8000 (PostgreSQL)
asyncpg (PostgreSQL)
pytds (SQL Server)
```

The `Python` package can be installed for `SQL server` with pip :

```
pip install "cloud-sql-python-connector[pytds]"
```

Example

```py
# insert statement
insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.text(
    "INSERT INTO my_table (id, title) VALUES (:id, :title)",
)

with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # insert into database
    db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, id="book1", title="Book One")

    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute("SELECT * from my_table").fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```